# user input link will go back to login once the user logged in it will go to the link earlier input instead of dashboard

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Sorry to ask but I don't what is the exact call on this.

I have a scenario for example I paste this link localhost/Dashboard/Treatment the user will go back to the login page once the user logged it will go to this localhost/Dashboard/Treatment instead of Main Page using asp.net.

I need is only the exactly the call on this process so that I will do the research.

Sorry beginner :)

Comment: Do you mean `returnurl` ?

Comment: So you want once user logged , the project will Jump to the specified page?

Comment: @XinranShen yes correct

Comment: @XinranShen yes correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using login control, you can use [DestinationPageUrl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.login.destinationpageurl?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Web_UI_WebControls_Login_DestinationPageUrl) property in your code.

If you just use things like text boxes and button controls, then in your Button_Click event, you can just use `Response.Redirect("DestinationHere")`.

If you don't want change anything in your page, you can add `return RedirectToAction({actionName}, {controllerName});` in your login method.